# Can any assumptions be made about the relationship between object.ToString() and IFormattable.ToString(string, IFormatProvider) for built-in types?

Tags: c#, string, iformattable

I'm writing some string output formatting code for aggregated records (think CSV format output). I'm trying to write it so that it leverages the built-in string formatting capabilities of many types via the `IFormattable.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` interface, in addition to the simple `object.ToString()`.

To reduce code duplication, it would be nice to be able to make some assumptions about the relationship between `object.ToString()` and `IFormattable.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)`.

For example, could it be relied upon to assume that `ToString() == ToString(null, null)`? Is there a default culture or format provider that maintains that mapping? Or is there no necessary relationship between the two?

Comment: You cannot make any assumptions for ToString since each implementation can override it and implement it as suited.

Comment: @RonDeijkers The question is only about built-in types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the MSDN documentation and .NET source code you can assume that for built-in types `ToString()` is equivalent to `ToString(null, null)` and `ToString("G", null)`.

There is some information about it in [Formatting Types in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx#OverrideToString) on MSDN.

For example according to that site `Int32.ToString()`

> Calls `Int32.ToString("G", NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)` to format the `Int32` value for the current culture.

If you check the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252), you will notice that `ToString()` calls

```
Number.FormatInt32(m_value, null, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
```

while `String ToString(String format, IFormatProvider provider)` calls

```
Number.FormatInt32(m_value, format, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
```

So the `format` is actually `null`, not `"G"`. It doesn't make a difference though, as `"G"` and `null` should be the same. [`NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(null)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.getinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`, so `Int32.ToString()` is equivalent to `Int32.ToString("G", null)` or `Int32.ToString(null, null)`.

You can double check it with [IFormattable.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation to see that `null`s indeed indicate default values for both parameters.

> Parameters
>
> format
>
> The format to use.
>
> -or-
>
> A null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) to use the default format defined for the type of the IFormattable implementation.
>
> formatProvider
>
> The provider to use to format the value.
>
> -or-
>
> A null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) to obtain the numeric format information from the current locale setting of the operating system.